# How to set element value dynamically based on for each loop count

Tags: foreach, xslt

Here is snippet of an xsl file that I am trying to make work.

I would like to change value for element `request-tot-queries` in the header based on loop count in the Body. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<HEADER>
  <request-tot-queries>$Counter</request-tot-queries>
</HEADER>
<Body>
 <xsl:for-each select="//Request/Responses/Pooled/ResidenceHistory/Residencies/Residency">
 <count><xsl:variable name="counter" select="position()"/></count>
  <xsl:if test="DateRange/To/Date[@Type!='Present']">
   <subject-query>
      .
      .
      .
   </subject-query>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
</Body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `count()` function:

```
<HEADER>
  <request-tot-queries>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(//Request/Responses/Pooled/ResidenceHistory/Residencies/Residency)"/>
  </request-tot-queries>
</HEADER>
```

Comment: Mads, I have the feeling that the OP maybe wants the count only for the nodes for which the `xsl:if` condition is `true()`.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - If that was the case, the OP would probably be trying to update the variable inside the `xsl:if`. I think Mads' answer is correct (+1).